# jquery autocomplete on Bootstrap search bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to put Jquery auto-complete in a bootstrap search bar. so when someone uses the search bar they show the tags below?

jquery auto-complete

```
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#text" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

});

Bootstrap search bar

```
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-5 col-sm-3">
                <form class="navbar-form" id="theSearchForm" name="theSearchForm" role="search" method="get" action="yoursearchfilescriptgoeshere">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:document.theSearchForm.submit();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></a>

                        </div>
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or is there no HTML element with the Id 'text'

Comment: I am not that good with jquery, I got that first part from the jquery ui site

Comment: If implemented correctly, I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work. See Hasan's answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can  find the working fiddel : https://jsfiddle.net/ywxm8rtr/

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
```

Comment: This will not work properly jQuery auto complete has styling issues with bootstrap as seen in your fiddle, this causes issues with the display div for results

Comment: due to i did'nt add the jquery ui css

Comment: Can you add it, I'm pretty sure there are issues with it even if you do add the css